# multiseat dual gpu, can I have 2 different drivers?

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon, gpu, proprietary-drivers

I have 2 radeon 7950, set up my multiseat, everything is working fine.
I use the free radeon drivers, and I'm pretty happy except for one thing, I can't test the gpu mining of bitcoins....
I'd like to know if it's feasible, possible to use 2 drivers, one per card ?